# React.js Inserting Component Into Child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<div>
   <p>Test</p>
</div>

<button onClick={AddPara()}> Add New Paragraph </button>

function AddPara (){
   return(
      <div>
         <p> New Para </p>
      </div>
   )
}
```

I am trying to get the new paragraph under the main Div that includes original paragraph (`<p>test</p>`), every time the button is clicked. I tried using ReactDOM.render however it throws me an error telling me to change the state rather using the DOM.

How would I do this?

I am trying to get the component dynamically rather than setting a specific limit of `<p>`. Instead of just having an extra `<p>` I am trying to insert `<p>` every time the button is click dynamically

end result I am trying to get:

```
<div> 
   <p> Test </p>
   <p> New Para </p>
   <p> New Para </p>
    ... keep adding <p>New Para</p> on button click
</div>
```

Comment: can you show the full component as its hard to suggest answer with part of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this demo what you want? If yes, please check this answer as accepted :)

Hope this helps,
Have a nice day!

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [] };

    this.addParagraph = this.addParagraph.bind(this);
  }
  addParagraph() {
    this.setState({ items: [...this.state.items, 'New Para'] });
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
    <p>Test</p>
    {this.state.items.map((item, index) => 
    <p key={'child_' + index}>{item}</p>
    )}
    <button onClick={this.addParagraph}>Add paragraph</button>
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Alex, Please, be sure, use `key` prop and use right `key` index, i recommend use text content + index or text id (if have) for improving performance and reduce issue. I am showed this as testing purpose :)

Comment: Thank you! Worked great

Comment: Nice. Wish you all the best :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to do something like this -

```
class AddPara extends React.Component {
   state = {
     paragraphText: "New Para"
   };

   addParagraph = () => {
      this.setState({ paragraphText: "Test" });
   }

   return(
      <div>
         <p>{this.state.paragraphText}</p>
         <button onClick={this.addParagraph}>Add New Paragraph</button>
      </div>
   )
}
```

When you click the button, it will now replace the content inside the paragraph with `Test` :)

Comment: it would be `Test` from the start as its what the default state is set to

Comment: Yup, you forgot to change the text in the setState I guess.

Comment: I am trying to add a new component under the <p> rather than just updating the current text

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are pretty new to react. That's the case, I would highly encourage you to read the documentation a bit.
Now about your issue, 
You just add a setState in the button click function, and show the new para based on the value change.

```
state = {
 showTime: 0
}
render () {
// Other code
<div>
   <p> Test </p>
{new Array(this.state.showTime).map(() => <p> New Para </p>)}
</div>

<button onClick={AddPara()}> Add New Paragraph </button>
}

function AddPara (){
   this.setState({showTime: this.state.showTime + 1});
}
```

Comment: Is this approach dynamic? If you click the button 5 times would the new <p> show up 5 times?

Comment: Ahh, you want to keep adding up the component. Give me a min, updating the answer

Answer (score 0):

From your question, you want to add a new paragraph on button click.

To do this you need to `map` over an array in your state to render each item in the array.

When you want to add a new paragraph, simply, add the new paragraph to the current state.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    paragraphs: ["hello world"]
  };

  addParagraph = () => {
    this.setState({
      paragraphs: [...this.state.paragraphs, "new paragraph"]
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        {this.state.paragraphs.map(paragraph => (
          <p>{paragraph}</p>
        ))}
        <button onClick={this.addParagraph}>Add Paragraph</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a [Codesandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/rj4p7lm6lm)

It should be noted though, that you can use the `updater` function within setState to ensure you do not do multiple calls during the same cycle.

```
addParagraph = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      paragraphs: [...prevState.paragraphs, "new paragraph"]
    }));
  };
```

See [setState Api docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for more info.